ALSA lib not outputing on custom linux
I am running a custom linux distribution on a custom board running on an ATSAMA5D29. I am managed to get the sound to work on the demo board, but when running it on custom hardware I get the error:
# speaker-test

speaker-test 1.2.11

Playback device is default
Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 1 channels
Using 16 octaves of pink noise
ALSA lib dlmisc.c:226:(snd_dlsym_verify) unable to verify version for symbol _snd_pcm_empty_open
ALSA lib dlmisc.c:348:(snd_dlobj_cache_get0) symbol _snd_pcm_empty_open is not defined inside [builtin]
Playback open error: -6,No such device or address

This happens even when running on the loopback card. Here's the list of devices (exactly the same output as the functioning demo board)
# aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Loopback [Loopback], device 0: Loopback PCM [Loopback PCM]
  Subdevices: 8/8
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
  Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
  Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
  Subdevice #7: subdevice #7
card 0: Loopback [Loopback], device 1: Loopback PCM [Loopback PCM]
  Subdevices: 8/8
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
  Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
  Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
  Subdevice #7: subdevice #7
card 1: CLASSD [CLASSD], device 0: CLASSD PCM snd-soc-dummy-dai-0 [CLASSD PCM snd-soc-dummy-dai-0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
# aplay -L
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
default:CARD=Loopback
    Loopback, Loopback PCM
    Default Audio Device
sysdefault:CARD=Loopback
    Loopback, Loopback PCM
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=Loopback,DEV=0
    Loopback, Loopback PCM
    Front output / input
surround21:CARD=Loopback,DEV=0
    Loopback, Loopback PCM
    2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
surround40:CARD=Loopback,DEV=0
    Loopback, Loopback PCM
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=Loopback,DEV=0
    Loopback, Loopback PCM
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=Loopback,DEV=0
    Loopback, Loopback PCM
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=Loopback,DEV=0
    Loopback, Loopback PCM
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=Loopback,DEV=0
    Loopback, Loopback PCM
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
default:CARD=CLASSD
    CLASSD, CLASSD PCM snd-soc-dummy-dai-0
    Default Audio Device
sysdefault:CARD=CLASSD
    CLASSD, CLASSD PCM snd-soc-dummy-dai-0
    Default Audio Device

The dmesg output may give some hints:
# dmesg | grep classd
device: 'fc048000.classd': device_add
bus: 'platform': add device fc048000.classd
PM: Adding info for platform:fc048000.classd
platform fc048000.classd: Not linking /ahb/apb/clock-controller@f0014000 - might never become dev
/ahb/apb/classd@fc048000 Dropping the fwnode link to /ahb/apb/clock-controller@f0014000
platform fc048000.classd: Not linking /ahb/apb/interrupt-controller@fc020000 - might never become dev
/ahb/apb/classd@fc048000 Dropping the fwnode link to /ahb/apb/interrupt-controller@fc020000
/ahb/apb/classd@fc048000 Linked as a fwnode consumer to /ahb/apb/pinctrl@fc038000
/ahb/apb/classd@fc048000 Dropping the fwnode link to /ahb/apb/pinctrl@fc038000/classd_default_pfets
/ahb/apb/classd@fc048000 Dropping the fwnode link to /ahb/apb/pinctrl@fc038000/classd_default_nfets
device: 'platform:fc038000.pinctrl--platform:fc048000.classd': device_add
devices_kset: Moving fc048000.classd to end of list
PM: Moving platform:fc048000.classd to end of list
platform fc048000.classd: Linked as a consumer to fc038000.pinctrl
/ahb/apb/classd@fc048000 Dropping the fwnode link to /ahb/apb/pinctrl@fc038000
bus: 'platform': add driver atmel-classd
bus: 'platform': __driver_probe_device: matched device fc048000.classd with driver atmel-classd
bus: 'platform': really_probe: probing driver atmel-classd with device fc048000.classd
atmel-classd fc048000.classd: no init pinctrl state
atmel-classd fc048000.classd: no sleep pinctrl state
atmel-classd fc048000.classd: no idle pinctrl state
atmel-classd fc048000.classd: PWM modulation type is Differential, non-overlapping is enabled
driver: 'atmel-classd': driver_bound: bound to device 'fc048000.classd'
bus: 'platform': really_probe: bound device fc048000.classd to driver atmel-classd

There is more information in sysfs and debugfs but none of it differed from the functioning board that I could tell. The relevant kernel configs are:
CONFIG_SND=y
CONFIG_SND_TIMER=y
CONFIG_SND_PCM=y
CONFIG_SND_DMAENGINE_PCM=y
CONFIG_SND_PCM_TIMER=y
CONFIG_SND_SUPPORT_OLD_API=y
CONFIG_SND_PROC_FS=y
CONFIG_SND_VERBOSE_PROCFS=y
CONFIG_SND_VERBOSE_PRINTK=y
CONFIG_SND_CTL_FAST_LOOKUP=y
CONFIG_SND_DEBUG=y
CONFIG_SND_DEBUG_VERBOSE=y
CONFIG_SND_DRIVERS=y
CONFIG_SND_HDA_PREALLOC_SIZE=64
CONFIG_SND_ARM=y
CONFIG_SND_SPI=y
CONFIG_SND_SOC=y
CONFIG_SND_SOC_GENERIC_DMAENGINE_PCM=y
CONFIG_SND_ATMEL_SOC=y
CONFIG_SND_ATMEL_SOC_CLASSD=y

If anyone has any ideas or other debug information I should provide please let me know.

Can you post a lspci?

@eyoung100 lspci: /sys/bus/pci/devices: No such file or directory

Didn't expect no output... What about sudo lshw?

Also, is the output of uname -a on the production hardware the same as the output of uname -a from the demo board? See Unable to load module: Disagrees about version of symbol module_layout

I don't have lshw installed on this build. The two unames:
Linux buildroot 6.6.23-linux4microchip-2024.04 #8 Thu Dec 12 16:20:47 EST 2024 armv7l GNU/Linux
&
Linux sama5 6.6.23-linux4microchip-2024.04 #1 Wed Nov 13 14:15:27 EST 2024 armv7l GNU/Linux

For this to work right both kernels need to be compiled exactly the same.  The link I posted and your initial output from sound-test seem to indicate 1.) that the demo board's kernel was compiled with the debug symbols on and the production has no symbols or 2.) Something happened in the kernel sources between Nov-13 and Dec-12.  Did you compile both kernels from the same source tree?

The problem seems to be from the libasound.so not being compiled correctly. I switched the instruction set from arm to thumb in the buildroot config and double checked that all the alsa packages were included in the buildroot side.
From buildroot .config:
#
# Audio and video applications
#
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_UTILS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_UTILS_ALSACONF=y
# BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_UTILS_ACONNECT is not set
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_UTILS_ALSACTL=y
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_UTILS_ALSALOOP=y
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_UTILS_ALSAMIXER=y
# BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_UTILS_ALSAUCM is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_UTILS_ALSATPLG is not set
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_UTILS_AMIDI=y
# BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_UTILS_AMIXER is not set
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_UTILS_APLAY=y
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_UTILS_APLAYMIDI=y
# BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_UTILS_ARECORDMIDI is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_UTILS_ASEQDUMP is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_UTILS_ASEQNET is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_UTILS_BAT is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_UTILS_IECSET is not set
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_UTILS_SPEAKER_TEST=y
BR2_PACKAGE_ATEST=y
# BR2_PACKAGE_AUMIX is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_BLUEZ_ALSA is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_DVBLAST is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_DVDAUTHOR is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_DVDRW_TOOLS is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_ESPEAK is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_FAAD2 is not set
BR2_PACKAGE_FFMPEG_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
# BR2_PACKAGE_FFMPEG is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_FLAC is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_FLITE is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_FLUID_SOUNDFONT is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_FLUIDSYNTH is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_GMRENDER_RESURRECT is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_GSTREAMER1 is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_JACK1 is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_JACK2 is not set
BR2_PACKAGE_KODI_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y

and
#
# Audio/Sound
#
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_LIB=y
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_LIB_DEVDIR="/dev/snd"
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_LIB_PCM_PLUGINS="all"
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_LIB_CTL_PLUGINS="all"
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_LIB_ALOAD=y
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_LIB_MIXER=y
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_LIB_PCM=y
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_LIB_RAWMIDI=y
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_LIB_HWDEP=y
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_LIB_SEQ=y
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_LIB_UCM=y
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_LIB_ALISP=y
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_LIB_OLD_SYMBOLS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_LIB_TOPOLOGY=y
# BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_PLUGINS is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_ALURE is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_AUBIO is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_BCG729 is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_CAPS is not set
BR2_PACKAGE_FDK_AAC_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
# BR2_PACKAGE_FDK_AAC is not set
BR2_PACKAGE_LIBAO=y
# BR2_PACKAGE_LIBBROADVOICE is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_LIBCANBERRA is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_LIBCDAUDIO is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_LIBCDDB is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_LIBCDIO is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_LIBCDIO_PARANOIA is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_LIBCODEC2 is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_LIBCUE is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_LIBCUEFILE is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_LIBEBUR128 is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_LIBG7221 is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_LIBGSM is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_LIBID3TAG is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_LIBILBC is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_LIBLO is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_LIBMAD is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_LIBMODPLUG is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_LIBMPDCLIENT is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_LIBREPLAYGAIN is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_LIBSAMPLERATE is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_LIBSIDPLAY2 is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_LIBSILK is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_LIBSNDFILE is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_LIBSOUNDTOUCH is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_LIBSOXR is not set
BR2_PACKAGE_LIBVORBIS=y
# BR2_PACKAGE_LILV is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_LV2 is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_MP4V2 is not set
BR2_PACKAGE_OPENAL_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
# BR2_PACKAGE_OPENAL is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_OPENCORE_AMR is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_OPUS is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_OPUSFILE is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_PORTAUDIO is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_SBC is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_SPANDSP is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_SPEEX is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_SPEEXDSP is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_SRATOM is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_TAGLIB is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_TINYALSA is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_TREMOR is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_VO_AACENC is not set
BR2_PACKAGE_WEBRTC_AUDIO_PROCESSING_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
# BR2_PACKAGE_WEBRTC_AUDIO_PROCESSING is not set

When I then did a make clean the speaker-test worked. I can't say for certain that switching the instruction sets was necessary, but definitely the make clean was necessary.
